# git and intelliJ project

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I created a project in intelliJ, now i would like to have it on git so i can revert changes etc.

First i selected the root of the project and then did this:

[image]

In preferences i setted the password etc:
[image]

However, if i look on the git website i can't see the project.
What is it i do wrong? Or am i missing an important step?

Comment: Check [this document](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally), you need to push the changes to the remote.

Comment: Generally there is no such thing as *git website* -- if you meant *github* website, in addition to the above advice [you have to create new repo](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository) on the other end and *push* changes from local to remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push your changes.

Bring up the Push shortcut by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, then typing Push. The list will filter down into the Git Push.